# Deploying on wildfly produces "Unable to acquire lock after 15 seconds" exception

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8, infinispan, distributed-caching

I am working with wildfly and i am getting "Unable to acquire lock after 15 seconds" exception. I don't know why am getting this exception.I tried with wildfly 8,9 and 10 as well.
Here is the decription of exception

thanks.

```
  17:30:56,743 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor] (default task-11) ISPN000136: Execution error: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000299: Unable to acquire lock after 15 seconds for key qDV8eCOJ_Dwt1aDZAMtOELUylOE7XNTN0IpHi34V and requestor GlobalTransaction:<null>:20:local. Lock is held by GlobalTransaction:<null>:19:local
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.DefaultLockManager$KeyAwareExtendedLockPromise.lock(DefaultLockManager.java:236)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.lockAndRecord(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:189)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.checkPendingAndLockKey(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:192)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.lockOrRegisterBackupLock(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.PessimisticLockingInterceptor.visitDataReadCommand(PessimisticLockingInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:113)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:85)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.enlistReadAndInvokeNext(TxInterceptor.java:345)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(TxInterceptor.java:330)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitDataReadCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleAll(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleDefault(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:85)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain.invoke(InterceptorChain.java:336)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.get(CacheImpl.java:412)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.DecoratedCache.get(DecoratedCache.java:437)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.AbstractDelegatingCache.get(AbstractDelegatingCache.java:286)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.coarse.CoarseSessionFactory.findValue(CoarseSessionFactory.java:164)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.coarse.CoarseSessionFactory.findValue(CoarseSessionFactory.java:66)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.InfinispanSessionManager.findSession(InfinispanSessionManager.java:224)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSessionManager.getSession(DistributableSessionManager.java:124)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.getSession(ServletContextImpl.java:725)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.getSession(ServletContextImpl.java:755)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:198)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:784)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`17:30:56,747 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-11) UT005023: Exception handling request to /webResults/jurisdiction/15/customization: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000299: Unable to acquire lock after 15 seconds for key qDV8eCOJ_Dwt1aDZAMtOELUylOE7XNTN0IpHi34V and requestor GlobalTransaction:<null>:20:local. Lock is held by GlobalTransaction:<null>:19:local
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.DefaultLockManager$KeyAwareExtendedLockPromise.lock(DefaultLockManager.java:236)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.lockAndRecord(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:189)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.checkPendingAndLockKey(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:192)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.lockOrRegisterBackupLock(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.PessimisticLockingInterceptor.visitDataReadCommand(PessimisticLockingInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:113)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:85)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.enlistReadAndInvokeNext(TxInterceptor.java:345)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(TxInterceptor.java:330)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitDataReadCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleAll(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleDefault(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:85)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain.invoke(InterceptorChain.java:336)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.get(CacheImpl.java:412)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.DecoratedCache.get(DecoratedCache.java:437)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.AbstractDelegatingCache.get(AbstractDelegatingCache.java:286)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.coarse.CoarseSessionFactory.findValue(CoarseSessionFactory.java:164)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.coarse.CoarseSessionFactory.findValue(CoarseSessionFactory.java:66)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.InfinispanSessionManager.findSession(InfinispanSessionManager.java:224)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSessionManager.getSession(DistributableSessionManager.java:124)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.getSession(ServletContextImpl.java:725)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.getSession(ServletContextImpl.java:755)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:198)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:784)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

`

Comment: Hmmm, hard to say looking at the execution. Can you get a thread dump of the node and post it in gist or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look the solution for this at [click here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/243458?tstart=0)

As per the above link, you should remove `<distributable/>` from web.xml
this is basically used for distributed environment.